# Creating custom jquery function and implementing it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently i'm willing to create my own jquery plugin.but i don't know where to begin.i googled for creating custom jquery function and tryed to implement it but it didn't work out.currently i'm wokring in asp.net mvc 4.plz help me,any good link ,idea will be great help for me.

Thanks in advance

---

```
(function($){ 
     $.fn.extend({ TestAlert: function(options) { alert("Hello Test") } }); 
})(jQuery);
```

and after this i added test.js file to my page and on button click i called `$("btnTest").click(function(){TestAlert();});` it didn't work out.

Comment: hi.. this site is not for that kind of questions... however, you may try to visit this, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring for your first try of making a jQuery plugin..

Comment: "tried to implement it but it didn't work out" - you need to show what did not work out so people can help you here. Most people here want to know that you have tried something. Your questions looks like you are asking "build the plugin for me". I know that's not your intention so I suggest you improve your question by adding some codes you have tried and showing us which is not working. You can ask unlimited questions here you know ;)

Comment: (function($){
        $.fn.extend({
            

           TestAlert: function(options) {
       alert("Hello Test") }
        });
        
    })(jQuery); and after this i added test.js file to my page and on button click i called $("btnTest").click(function(){TestAlert();}); it didn't work out.

Comment: i tried this too  <input type="button" id="T"  value="Click"/>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.YourName = function () {
        alert('test1');
    }
    $("#T").click(function () {
        $(this).YourName();
    });


    
</script> but didn't work out

Comment: yes i made it some how .the solution to begin jquery plugin :<div id="TestDiv">
hello world
</div>
 <input type="button" id="T"  value="Click"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#T").click(function () {
           
            $.fn.YourName();
            $("#TestDiv").TestHide();
        });
        $.fn.YourName = function () {
            alert('test1');
        }
        $.fn.TestHide = function () {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        TestAlert: function (options) {
            $(this).click(function () {
                alert("Hello Test");
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And then call it like:

```
$("#btnTest").TestAlert();
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/HhvX2/1/).

The problem with your current code is that defining the following:

```
$.fn.extend({ TestAlert: function(options) { alert("Hello Test") } });
```

You are extending the jquery fn itself with a function that will alert a message when called like directly like:

```
$.fn.TestAlert();
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/4QAU2/) to see this.

But as mentioned in the comments you should probably take a good look at the [jQuery plugins/authoring wiki](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for a good explanation of how to create your own plugins.